# How to connect user with a login cookie in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, cookies, encryption, authentication

First of all, I am testing on localhost. I have this index.php file which contains the following "remember me" checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="login_remember" name="login_remember">
```

The login form posts to loginvalidate.php, which includes the following php script. I have included a lot of comments to ease the process of reading my code. Note that I'm pretty sure that everything below works fine.

```
if (isset($_POST['login_submit'])) {  //SETS VARIABLES FROM FORM
$email = $_POST[trim('login_email')];
$password = $_POST['login_password'];
$remember = isset($_POST['login_remember']) ? '1' : '0';

$db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle,$sql_database);  //OPENING TABLE

$query = "SELECT password FROM registeredusers WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query) or die (mysqli_error($db_handle));

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($numrows!=0)  //IF EMAIL IS REGISTERED
{
  if ($row['password'] == $password) {  //IF PASSWORD IN DATABASE == PASSWORD INPUT FROM FORM
        if ($remember == '1'){  //IF USER WANTS TO BE REMEMBERED
        $randomNumber = rand(99,999999);  //RANDOM NUMBER TO SERVE AS A KEY
        $token = dechex(($randomNumber*$randomNumber));  //CONVERT NUMBER TO HEXADECIMAL FORM
        $key = sha1($token . $randomNumber);
        $timeNow = time()*60*60*24*365*30;  //STOCKS 30 YEARS IN THE VAR

         $sql_database = "registeredusers";
         $sql_table = "rememberme";

         $db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle,$sql_database);  //OPENING TABLE

         $query_remember = "SELECT email FROM rememberme WHERE email = '$email'";  //IS THE USER IN TABLE ALREADY
         $result = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query_remember) or die (mysqli_error($db_handle));

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {  //IF USER IS ALREADY IN THE REMEMBERME TABLE
         $query_update = "UPDATE rememberme SET
         email      = '$email'
         user_token = '$token'
         token_salt = '$randomNumber'
         time       = '$timeNow'";
    }
    else {  //OTHERWISE, INSERT USER IN REMEMBERME TABLE
         $query_insert = "INSERT INTO rememberme
        VALUES( '$email', '$token', '$randomNumber', '$timeNow' )";
    }
  setcookie("rememberme", $email . "," . $key, $timenow);
    }
          header('Location: homepage.php');  //REDIRECTS: SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
        exit();
    }
```

Then, when I close the internet browser and come back to index.php, I want the cookie to automatically connect the user. This is in my index.php:

```
include 'db_connect.php';
    $sql_database = "registeredusers";
    $db_found = mysqli_select_db($db_handle,$sql_database);  //OPENING TABLE
    session_start();
    if (isset($_COOKIE['rememberme'])) {
        $rememberme = explode(",", $_COOKIE["rememberme"]);
        $cookie_email = $rememberme[0];
        $cookie_key = $rememberme[1];

        $query_remember = "SELECT * FROM rememberme WHERE email = '$cookie_email'";  //IS THE USER IN TABLE ALREADY
        $result_remember = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query_remember) or die (mysqli_error($db_handle));

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_remember);
            $token = $row['user_token'];
            $randomNumber = $row['token_salt'];
        $key = sha1($token . $randomNumber);  //ENCRYPT TOKEN USING SHA1 AND THE RANDOMNUMBER AS SALT

        if ($key == $cookie_key){
            echo "lol";
        }
    }
```

The problem is, it never echoes "lol". Also, does anyone have any insight on how I could connect the users? AKA, what should go inside these lines:

```
if ($key == $cookie_key){
            echo "lol";
        }
```

Thank you! I'm still new to PHP and SQL so please bear with me if I have made some beginner errors.

EDIT!: After looking again and again at my code, I think that my error might lie in these lines. I'm not sure about the syntax, and the method I am using to store values into $token and $randomNumber:

```
$query_remember = "SELECT * FROM rememberme WHERE email = '$cookie_email'";  //IS THE USER IN TABLE ALREADY
    $result_remember = mysqli_query($db_handle, $query_remember) or die (mysqli_error($db_handle));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_remember);
        $token = $row['user_token'];
        $randomNumber = $row['token_salt'];
```

Answer (score 28):

A login script in PHP can be implemented using [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

## Using Sessions

Making it simple, sessions are unique and lives as long as the page is open (or until it timeouts). If your browser is closed, the same happens to the session.

### How to use it?

They are pretty simple to implement. First, make sure you start sessions at the beginning of each page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

*Note: It's important that this call comes before of **any page output**, or it will result in an "headers already sent" error.*

Alright, now your session is up and running. What to do next? It's quite simple: user sends it's login/password through login form, and you validate it. If the login is valid, store it to the session:

```
if($validLoginCredentials){
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['user_login'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $name;
}
```

or as an array (which I prefer):

```
if($validLoginCredentials){
    $_SESSION['user'] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'login' => 'login',
        'whichever_more' => $informationYouNeedToStore
    );
}
```

Ok, now your user is logged in. So how can you know/check that? Just check if the session of an user exists.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){ // OR isset($_SESSION['user']), if array
// Logged In
}else{
// Not logged in :(
}
```

Of course you could go further, and besides of checking if the session exists, search for the session-stored user ID in the database to validate the user. It all depends on the how much security you need.

In the simplest application, there will never exist a $_SESSION['user'] unless you set it manually in the login action. So, simply checking for it's existence tells you whether the user is logged in or not.

Loggin out: just destroy it. You could use

```
session_destroy();
```

But keep in mind that this will destroy **all sessions** you have set up for that user. If you also used $_SESSION['foo'] and $_SESSION['bar'], those will be gone as well. In this case, just unset the specific session:

```
unset($_SESSION['user']);
```

And done! User is not logged in anymore! :)

Well, that's it. To remind you again, these are ***very simple*** login methods examples. You'll need to study a bit more and improve your code with some more layers of security checks depending on the security requirements of your application.

Comment: Thanks. This definitely helped me understanding sessions and cookies, which I am still not used to. I still have my problem though, as it doesn't completely answer my question. I will be editing my question, as I think I know where is my error.

Comment: This is far from secure or usable. It outlines the basic mechanics and suggests an implementation. The disclaimers throughout the answer should be taken seriously!

Comment: I guess you mean: time() + 7200

Answer (score 6):

reason behind your code is not working is

```
  setcookie("rememberme", $email . "," . $key, $timenow); // this is getting expire exactly at same time when it is set
```

replace it with

```
 setcookie("rememberme", $email . "," . $key, time() * 3600);//expire after 1hour
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It makes sense. The full code still doesn't work though, as it doesn't echo "lol" when refreshing on index.php. I have edited my question to include your fix.

Comment: Should be "time() + 3600" (plus, not multiplied), to expire after one hour.

Answer (score 0):

```
time()*60*60*24*365*30
```

this time is greater than 9999 year also you didn't need to set this horror cookie time.
that cookie time you were set is greater than 9999 years and php not allow for this configure.
in my opinion the best solution is setup new expire cookie time lower than 9999 :))

Comment: time() + (60*60*24*365*30)