# Logout on website?

Tags: php, html

I'm implementing a login/logout system on a very simple website I've created.  I've successfully implemented logging in through sessions, which I read up on here

[How to connect user with a login cookie in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740543/how-to-connect-user-with-a-login-cookie-in-php)

The first answer described sessions pretty well and I think I have the hang of it.  My only questions is logging out.  Where do I put the statement session_destroy();?  Obviously I'd like to put it in the logout link, to simultaneously destroy the session and send them back to the homepage.  Let me share my code for the link of login and logout (it's the same on all pages).

```
<a href= <?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) 
    echo"index.php";
else 
    echo"login.php"; ?>>
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    echo"Logout"; 
else
    echo"Login";
?>
</a>
```

So I made it so if your session is active, you'll see a "logout" link that redirects you to the homepage.  Else, youll just see the login link and be directed to the login page.  So how do I make it when you see the logout link it also destroys the session?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want *logout.php* instead of *index.php*?

Comment: dont forget to put quotes around your **href** attribute. It takes a string so wrap it in quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an href attribute is supposed to be wrapped in quotations.

```
    href="<?php echo $this_var; ?>"
```

then for your problem, I suggest your could inject a variable in your url upon redirection when logging out,like so.

```
<?
    echo 'login.php?value=logout';
?>
```

and in your **login.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['logout']))
    {   
       unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
       //use this if you only want the user_id session to be unset.
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the Logout text into an hyperlink that calls a php script which unsets the user_id attribute from the session or destroys it using `session_destroy()`.

```
<a href= <?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) 
    echo"index.php?logout=true";
else 
    echo"login.php"; ?>>
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    echo"Logout"; 
else
    echo"Login";
?>
</a>
```

And in index.php, on the top of the script add the folowing:

```
if (isset$_GET['logout']))
    session_destroy();
```

Comment: I kind of get that, but i'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `logout.php` file and put this content to it.

```
<?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    // and delete all the sessions you have created. 
    // or use session_destroy(); 
}
?>
```

I would rather use a custom object to store all my session information rather than directly storing it in the random `$_SESSION` associative array values

Anyhow your page code presented in the question should be modified as below

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])):?>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>; 
<?php endif; ?>
```