# Redirect a user to their profile on their first login

Tags: php, oop, redirect, authentication

I need to redirect a user to their profile when they log in for the first time, so that they can fill in more information. How could I do this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18743644/2752041) could give you a head start. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you break down your sentence a bit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood exactly what you want to do, but you can get all the fields when the user register, select from your data all fields and check the null or empty fields. Then you redirect the user if the profile user still need fields to be filled. Does it help you?

Thanks!

Comment: No. I have four field in the record and do not want to but when it does the registration and enter the login I want it to redirect the first sign him to do in order to change the other 10 fields that are needed to add to the profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a column in database that will increment for each user login, like a login counter, so when the user will first time signup, the field will be 0, so during login you will increment and check this value, if the value is 1 then you will redirect the user to fill in the rest of the data to his profile page.

I hope this is what you wanted. If i missed anything let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Put all required fields in the registration page, so you don't have to do this.
2. Determine at login whether their profile is missing required data.

While you could also record how many times a user has logged in, this has a problem when applied to your workflow; if the user logs in the first time, then closes the browser and logs in again it would break the flow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to capture all required information on Registeration page
2. In case you miss or need more info
   a. You may show pop up with message about missing information and update profile page and ask user to redirect to profile page.
   b. You show the progress bar on UI saying completion of profile page (e.g  40%)

Again, different product flow might have different scenario's above are just suggestions