# redirecting folder to file using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

A friend wants me to implement basic file security on his site that he can look after himself.

I think the simplest option is to put a .htaccess file into the folder he wants to protect and that will redirect all requests to a php file in the root.
The php file will then check if the user is logged in and serve the file or request a fixed shared login password.

It's going ok so far except for two problems.
Firstly I can't get the htaccess file work based on the directory it is located in - I can only manage it by hard coding the directory into the htaccess file.
Secondly, I can get the php file to know the url of the file that was requested.

Any help and pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are wanting to do can be done a little more easily with an .htpasswd setup.

You will just place this in an .htaccess of the directory you are trying to protect and all of the sub-directories will be protected as well.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And then create an .htpasswd file and use a tool like [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to generate the credentials.

Alternatively, the way you are suggesting to do it will require the use of either cookies or sessions and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740543/how-to-connect-user-with-a-login-cookie-in-php) is another question that should help a bit more with setting that up.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks!  Didn't know about htpasswd, however it looks like I can't use it because of the inability to logout.  It works really well though, even blocking images on other pages if you aren't logged in.

I've just used the session variable so far to pass the requested url but I still can't get the htaccess file to use the local folder and I have to hard code it like this ...

RewriteRule ^privateDirectory/(.*)$ https://example.com/private.php?redir=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

It is this bit ^privateDirectory/(.*)$ I need to work from the directory it is in.