# Separate user with cookie

Tags: php, cookies

If username and password are true, it will redirect to profile.php. I use cookie to separate user at profile.php. Is is suitable? If not, please advice me how I code. I don't want to use get method if possible.

````
<?php

  include('config.php');

  $cookie = isset($_COOKIE['cookie']);

  if($cookie) { header('Location: profile.php'); }

  else {

    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/user.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.css">

          <div id="center"><div id="login-area">Login Here<br><br><form method="post">

          <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          <input type="text" id="usr-pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="user"><hr><br>

          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          <input type="password" id="usr-pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password" name="pass"><hr><br>

          <input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" name="login">

          </form></div></div>
    ';

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

      if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $query = 'SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?';

        $stmt = $conn -> prepare($query);
        $stmt -> bind_param('s', $user);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> store_result();

        if($stmt -> num_rows > 0) {

          $stmt -> bind_result($password);
          $stmt -> fetch();

          if($password == $pass) {

            setcookie('cookie', $user);
            header('Location: profile.php');

          } else { header('Location: login.php'); } //echo 'wrong password';
        } else { header('Location: login.php'); } //echo 'account not exist';
      } else { header('Location: login.php'); } //echo 'input both username & password';
    }
  }
?>

<!-- This is profile.php -->

<?php

  include('config.php');

  $cookie = isset($_COOKIE['cookie']);

  if(!$cookie) { header('Location: login.php'); }

  else {

    $username = $_COOKIE['cookie'];

    $sql = 'SELECT id, email, birthday, work FROM user WHERE username = ?';

    $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> store_result();
    $stmt -> bind_result($id, $email, $birthday, $work);
    $stmt -> fetch();

    //show data here.
  }

?>```
````

Comment: All explanations here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740543/how-to-connect-user-with-a-login-cookie-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sessions.

At the top of the file, before any output has been sent, add `session_start();`

Once the user is authenticated (the username and password are found in the database), set a session variable like so: `$_SESSION['logged_id'] = true;`

For every page that people must be logged in to view, put `session_start();` at the top of the file and you can check if the person is logged in with:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    echo 'Logged in!;
}
```

or

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : ?>
    Logged in
<?php endif ?>
```

Documentation/examples: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php